# Renaming Duplicated Target: Where do I fix the reference to the default plist name?

Tags: xcode, duplicates

Environment: Xcode 4.6.3

I wish to duplicate a target and rename it from the default ' copy' to ' (Simulator)'.

Steps that I've done:

1) Select the target & contextually click the 'duplicate' option.

2) Click/Select the copied target name and modify it to chose name: ' (Simulator)'.

3) Manage Schemes: delete the generated (copy) and auto-generate new scheme.

   ...the newly-generated scheme should be correctly labeled with '...(Simulator)'.

**Problems...**

Either I get a compiler error of a conflicting piece of code, or I get the following:

> Error: could not read data from
>   '/Users/ric/Desktop/iPhone5_support/CG-Mobile copy-Info.plist': The
>   file “CG-Mobile copy-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is
>   no such file.

**Question:** What's the simplest way to 
 a) duplicate and 
 b) rename this duplicate so that I don't screw-up the build?

Answer (score 3):

In these situations I often just manually fix things in the project.pbxproj with a text editor.

1. Close Xcode
2. Open project.pbxproj in a text editor (Emacs, Vim, SublimeText, etc)
3. Search/replace CG-Mobile copy-Info.plist with your new name.
4. Save.
5. Reopen xcode.